# Script for retrieving emails from Outlook

Tags: email, vbscript, outlook, attachment

This is my script for retrieving emails from Outlook inbox and store their attachments.

The problem is that is not working properly. It is able to collect the attachments from unread emails and store them into `SavePath`, but somehow it is stopping when it has read three emails.

The strange thing is that it is able to collect the remaining emails when it is executed again, but not all remaining unread emails.

**E.g:** I have 6 unread emails at Inbox, the first time it is executed only 3 emails were read and their attachments were collected. The second time it is executed, it reads the next 2 emails. The third time it is executed, the remaining email was read.

I can't figure out what is happening and why not all emails are read at once.

```
Dim SavePath
Dim Subject
Dim FileExtension

SavePath = "C:\IN\"
Subject = "'Transfer File'"
FileExtension = "ARmessage"

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6) 'Inbox

Set colItems = objFolder.Items
Set colFilteredItems = colItems.Restrict("[Unread]=true")
Set colFilteredItems = colFilteredItems.Restrict("[Subject] = " & Subject)

For Each objMessage In colFilteredItems
    intCount = objMessage.Attachments.Count
    If intCount > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To intCount
            ' if right(Ucase(objMessage.Attachments.Item(i)),9) = FileExtension then
                objMessage.Attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile SavePath &  _
                    objMessage.Attachments.Item(i).FileName
            ' End If
        Next
        objMessage.Unread = False
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use "for each" with a collection that you are changing - restricted collection is dynamic, as you mark the messages read, the collection changes. Use a down "for" loop:

```
dim k
For k = colFilteredItems.Count to 1 step -1
  set objMessage  = colFilteredItems.Item(k)
  ...
next
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dmitry. After apply your suggestion It now launches 'Syntax error' message.

Comment: Now i get this error: `Invalid loop control variable`

Comment: Oh, wait you have another loop that uses "I". Use soothing else for the loop variable (see above)

Comment: OMG! I didn't realize. Finally it is working like a charm. Thanks Dmitry!